# How to use assign function with respect to value created by melt function?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, tidyverse

I'm learning some basics of Python and I'm trying to emulate a simple code I wrote in R, but there is an issue when I apply a function on a new variable.

This is what I wrote in R:

```
df1 <- df %>%
   select(var1,,var2,var4,var5,var6) %>%
   gather(var4,var5,var6,key = "key_name",value = "value_name") %>%
   mutate(value_name=value_name*1000)
```

and this is what I wrote in Python:

```
df1= (df
    .filter(['var1','var2','var3','var4','var5','var6'])
    .melt(id_vars=['var1','var2'])
    .assign(value = df['value']*1000)
)
```

This gives me an error, and I understand that it's because when I try to use `.assign` after `.melt`, the variable `'value'` doesn't exist on the data frame `df`.

I know I could do something like:

```
df1= (df
    .filter(['var1','var2','var3','var4','var5','var6'])
    .melt(id_vars=['var1','var2'])
)
df1=df1.assign(value = df['value']*1000)
```

but I would like to have all the functions one after the other without defining more than one time my data frame `df1`. If it is not possible to do something like this I would like to know why.

Advanced greetings.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your original df or a [mcve](help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you. I will include it in future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change:

```
assign(value = df['value']*1000)
```

to

```
assign(value=lambda df: df['value']*1000)
```